# Riddle - answer is a URL or picture

Tags: riddle

*My cousins have a lump or two, 

But I have none. 

I'm coloured like a grassy hill; 

Never seen one.*

*A war is fought within my bounds, 

Let's hope that peace will be found. 

I may sound like a pub on the roadside, 

But on the internet I reside.*

The answer to this riddle can be given as a URL or as a picture.

*Disclaimer*: this time, no maths involved! That's a promise (and this is not a hint).

**Edit:** Leo's answer taught me more than I realised there was to know about the solution to this riddle. Feel free to edit my question in order to make it fit his answer better. He's done his research better than I did!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice riddle...  I think I got it though...

> Bunchie is the name of this mythical internet creature that started on genmay and became huge rather quickly.  I remember when enough members on genmay even took over drawball to make a giant picture of Bunchie... http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/bunchie

And to address the second half...

> The second half of the riddle is about the Puzzling Beta chat room which is called "Green Llama" in reference to Bunchie.

Comment: I meant the second thing you mention (didn't realise it was named after an internet meme!) If you add a bit of explanation, I'll accept this answer. I thought this one would go quickly...

Comment: When I read the riddle I thought of a chat room, found the puzzling chat room and realized it was named green thing.  Then remembered seeing that cartoon on forums almost 10 years ago.  :) let me see what I can dig up

Comment: I'm learning so much from your answer! I think I'll write my own reference answer with what I intended, accept your answer, and then throw open the question for edits.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is:

> [Windows XP default Wallpaper](http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg)

A war is fought within my bounds, 
Let's hope that peace will be found. 
I may sound like a pub on the roadside, 
But on the internet I reside.

> Lots of people create/delete files and folders on their desktop.

Comment: Nope. Why does it sound like a pub, and who are the cousins? +1 anyway. (PS: still here? I thought you were at work!)

Comment: "a war is fought within my bounds" makes it sound like a pub. (self referencing). Cousins: more hills :P

Comment: Ah, nice one! But (the second part of) Leo's answer is what I was thinking of. I took part in the big puzzling.SE battle in the Green Llama today, and thought it'd make a nice riddle! Should have tried to find out where the name came from first, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record (but Leo's answer is much better), the answer I was looking for is:

> [The Green Llama](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-green-llama)

*My cousins have a lump or two, 

 But I have none.*

> The llama is closely related to the dromedary and Bactrian camels with one and two humps respectively, but it itself is humpless.

*I'm coloured like a grassy hill;*

> Green.

*Never seen one.*

> It's not a real llama, just something on the internet!

*A war is fought within my bounds,*

> This chatroom is the site of a big argument about what puzzling.SE should look like, which I described in one of my posts there as a "war"...

*Let's hope that peace will be found.*

> ... but we're hoping for an amicable solution.

*I may sound like a pub on the roadside,*

> Well, it *does*. "How about a pint at the Green Llama?"

*But on the internet I reside.*

> Simple truth.